# How to setup mainline kernel

Tags: linux, kernel

I need to set up mainline kernel on my ubuntu machine.

I went to the kernel.org and downloaded the the zip file and unzipped it.

Now, I have the copy on my local machine. But how to keep it updated, do I have to download the zip again and again? Isn't there a way like in git, to checkout the code to update it regularly?

Please refer me to appropriate link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best option here is to use the Mainline kernel PPA. It avoids to download, extract, compile and install the kernel manually each time (including having to configure it correctly).

You should read this : https://askubuntu.com/questions/160535/how-do-i-add-the-mainline-kernel-ppa

But since you're talking about git, you can also use directly the Linux git repository, linux-stable for example, and checking out the branch and the tag you want.